# NodeManager process failing due to binding error after starting on master

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to run a wordcount job on a multi-node cluster. Every time I start the processes, the NodeManager starts successfully but then dies out. The log file shows the following error:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:8040] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.<init>(Server.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.<init>(Server.java:2203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.<init>(RPC.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server.<init>(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:505)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.getServer(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Builder.build(RPC.java:742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.createServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.getServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:132)
    ... 13 more
```

I tried to kill the process at 0.0.0.0:8040, but that results in a loss of connection with the virtual machine. My /etc/hosts file is as shown below:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.50.2 master
192.168.50.8 slave-e1a2365d-ef73-4c94-8212-7d607e4ae0f3
192.168.50.9 slave-bbd66c22-678c-474e-94cf-095dfcc11d5c

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

I am not sure how to fix this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to see your code ? The cluster has been tested before your wordcount ? Are you using Cloudera ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your port is already in use from [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException)

How to track down the problem

1)identify which port the program is trying to bind to

2)as root use netstat -a -t --numeric-ports -p to list the ports that are in use by number and process. (On OS/X you need to use lsof)

3)identify the port that is in use and the program that is in use

4)Make sure the hostname is valid:try to ping it; use ifconfig to list the network interfaces and their IP addresses.

5)try and identify why it is in use. telnet   and pointing a web browser at it are both good tricks.

6)change the configuration of one of the programs to listen on a different port.

Hope that helps